# Handle Conversion Error using Resource Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I have Internationalized my MvC4 application.Inside model there is one property

```
public float Fuels{ get; set; }
```

When i typed string value inside textbox corresponding to this property,I got a validation error `'The value 'ff' is not valid for Fuels.'`.But i want to handle it using resource file.If i have selected arabic then validation error should come in arabic..
I got required message using the following code

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(@Application.Resources.Admin.Country),
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "FuelReq")]
```

I have tried the following way:-

```
public class FLoatAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
    {
        private const string defaultErrorMessage = "{0}  is required.";
        public FLoatAttribute()
            : base(defaultErrorMessage)
        {
        }
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            float objFloat;
            return float.TryParse(Convert.ToString(value), out objFloat);
        }
    }
```

and tried using regular expression inside model.But it didn't worked.
Pls help me.